# Boundary of two sets

Tags: general-topology

If $b,c,k,i$ denotes the boundary,closure,complement and interior operator respectively and $A,B $ $\subseteq X$ where $X$ is a topological space.Suppose $bA=bB$ holds it  does not imply $A=B $ because we can take the example $b(0,1)=\{0,1\}=b[0,1]$ but $(0,1) \neq [0,1]$.I was thinking if boundaries of two sets are equal ,Can we conclude any relation between $A$ and $B$ that means Can we conclude anything concrete may be in terms of closure or interior of the two sets??

Comment: Given an arbitrary set $A$, the set which has the same boundary in metric space should be $bA$ with up to countable number of holes, any set $B$ s.t. $int A\subseteq B\subseteq\bar A$ or $int A^c\subseteq B\subseteq\bar A^c$, or possibly something else.

Comment: @AranKomatsuzaki what is meant by holes.Are you trying to hint at the disconnectedness of the space?

Comment: For example, if an unit circle is the boundary, I mean the unit circle from which up to countable number of elements are deleted.

Comment: By the way, any clopen set shares the same boundary as the sets which share the same boundary as sets such as $X$ or $\emptyset$.

Comment: @AranKomatsuzaki the clopen sets which are both closed and open say $A$ will have $bA=cA \setminus iA=A \setminus A=\phi$

Comment: Yes. That's what I thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think $A=[a,b]$ and $B=(-\infty,a)\cup(b,\infty)$. In your notations $b A=b B$. Think both examples, yours and mine.

Comment: $bA=cA \cap ckA =\{a,b\}=cB \cap ckB=bB$ where $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ equipped with usual topology.

Comment: This example, your example and @Henrik's example illustrates that there is no relation between $cA$ and $cB$ while $bA=bB$.

Answer (score 0):

To build on your example: The boundary of $\{0,1\}$ is also $\{0,1\}$, so you can have disjoint sets with the same boundary.

Comment: Are you considering singletons $\{0 \}$ and $\{1\} $ $\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ under the standard topology??

Comment: I've fixed my LaTeX, and yes: using the standard topology.